# canvas rotate img horizontally

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, rotation

I am working on animation optimisation and i wanted to try out canvas to see how it performs but i am not experienced well in canvas and i dont know how to prepare concept of this kind of animation.

this is the gif that shows how animation should rotate like:

[image]

this is my current code of js:

```
var cvs = document.getElementById('coin-spin'),
    ctx = cvs.getContext('2d'),
    w = cvs.width = 400,
    h = cvs.height = 400,
    cx = w / 2,
    cy = h / 2,
    a = 0;

var img = new Image();

var loop = function() {
    // BG
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ccc';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    // draw image
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * a);
    ctx.translate(-cx, -cy);
    ctx.drawImage(img, cx - (img.width / 2), cy -  (img.height / 2));
    ctx.restore();

    // axis
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cx, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(cx, h);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, cy);
    ctx.lineTo(w, cy);
    ctx.stroke();

    //mod angle
    a++;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};

img.onload = function() {
    loop();
};

img.src = 'https://image.ibb.co/gqkeXx/coin.png';
```

and the working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j889keyk/3/) on fiddle.

Could someone show how to add to the code so the image would rotate horizontally like on the gif?

**EDIT ----**

I added the spin, as it was also something to do, but still struggling on how to rotate it.

Comment: you could approximate rotation by mapping the horizontal scale of the image to a sine wave. there would be glaring differences with the one in your gif though since it seems to keep perspective correct (which takes quite a bit more math and work), and your GIF also renders the side of the coin. if you really want to do that, you'd need a 3d model of your coin and a 3d rendering engine like three.js.

Comment: lets forget for the moment of 3d version, and side of the coin, for the moment i just need the simple 2d rotation, to see how it can be done and how it will perform, its hard to find any resources on the topic, i couldnt make it to work myself yet

Comment: you can find a first step in the right direction here : https://jsfiddle.net/ozp9uys2/ but as you can see, you now have a problem with the rotation of the coin you have already applied.

Comment: in order to get around that, you need an offscreen texture. see my full answer for details and a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around the problem of rotating the object along two axes (faking one by mapping width to a sine wave), you can use an offscreen canvas to render the coin rotating around one axis, then render that canvas applying the second rotation ;

```
//make an offscreen canvas for rendering the coin rotating around one axis
var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

var cvs = document.getElementById('coin-spin'),
        ctx = cvs.getContext('2d'),
        w = cvs.width = 400,
        h = cvs.height = 400,
        cx = w / 2,
        cy = h / 2,
        a = 0;

    var img = new Image();
    var frameCount = 0;

    var loop = function() {
    frameCount++;

    // BG
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ccc';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    offscreenContext.fillStyle = '#ccc';
    offscreenContext.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    //determine how wide to render the offscreen canvas so we can fake
    //rotation around the second axis
    var imgRenderWidth = offscreenCanvas.width * Math.sin(frameCount/10.0)

    //render the coin rotating around one axis to the offscreen canvas
    offscreenContext.save();
    offscreenContext.translate(img.width/2, img.height/2);
    offscreenContext.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * a);
    offscreenContext.translate((0-img.width)/2, (0-img.height)/2);
    offscreenContext.drawImage(img, 0,0);
    offscreenContext.restore();

        // draw offscreen canvas to the screen with our precalculated width
        ctx.save();
        ctx.drawImage(offscreenCanvas, cx - (imgRenderWidth / 2), cy -  (offscreenCanvas.height / 2), imgRenderWidth, offscreenCanvas.height);
        ctx.restore();

        // axis
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(cx, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(cx, h);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, cy);
        ctx.lineTo(w, cy);
        ctx.stroke();

        //mod angle
        a++;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };

    //once the image has loaded, we know what size our offscreen canvas needs to be
    img.onload = function() {
    offscreenCanvas.width = img.width;
    offscreenCanvas.height = img.height;

        loop();
    };

    img.src = 'https://image.ibb.co/gqkeXx/coin.png';

    //prepare the offscreen context so we can render to it later
    var offscreenContext =  offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ay3h5vuo/